# How do I get the new C++ threading support on Mac OS X with clang?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, clang

I just want to compile the following program on Mac OSX 10.8 using Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66):

```
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello world";

}
```

But I get:

```
../src/FirstCAgain.cpp:13:10: fatal error: 'thread' file not found
#include <thread>
```

I enabled c++11 support and I'm using the Eclipse C/C++ Development Tooling.

The question is: How do I get the new C++ threading support on Mac OS X ?

Comment: This is a dup of many many questions, Apple only ship an ancient GCC so its library doesn't have C++11 support, you need to use the alternative libc++ library for C++11 features, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14150421/981959, or install a newer GCC

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the new `libc++`, which isn't the default:

```
clang++ -stdlib=libc++ threadtest.cpp
```

(Of course you also need to include iostream, but I assume that wasn't you confusion.)

Comment: Hi thanks that seems to work. Now I get "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const" when linking but that seems to be a problem of my CDT setup.

Comment: fyi, here nearly 3 years later, worth noting that it is the default now