# c++11: clang refuses numeric_limits<> in my template definition, while gcc accepts it - which is right?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang

The offending code:

```
template <class Bar, 
         size_t MAX_SIZE = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()>
size_t foo(Bar const& b) { omitted... }
```

It compiles fine on gcc 4.7.2 with `-std=c++11`. On clang 3.0 I get the following error:

```
foo.hpp:35:28: error: non-type template argument of type 'unsigned long' is not an integral constant expression
         size_t MAX_SIZE = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()>
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As far as I can tell, I am supposed to be able to use `numeric_limits` in this way in c++11. Is clang wrong here, or am I unaware of something?

EDIT:

Compilation flags are: `clang++ -o foo.o -c -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -g -I. foo.cpp`

Comment: Which stdlib do you use with Clang? This is not a compiler problem, it depends on whether your standard library implementation put a `constexpr` identifier before `numeric_limits<T>::max()`. Also, 3.0 is rather old, so if you're using libc++ with that, it might just be too old to have the change.

Comment: I guess since adding `-stdlib=libc++` changed nothing, it might be a problem of too old clang?

Comment: Are you `using std::size_t` or `using namespace std`?

Comment: Yeah, I had the namespace in there at some point. It does not change anything.

Comment: Switching `size_t` to `unsigned long` yields the same error?

Comment: Even `int` is the same. Look at the other answers, the problem is probably with the version of clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code compiles just fine with clang++ 3.2, see [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/44xxiv%244).

I would say there is nothing wrong with your code but you should upgrade to a newer version of clang.

Note: The code doesn't compile with the Intel C++ Compiler 13.0.1 due to a compiler bug (thanks @Xeo):

```
Compilation finished with errors:
source.cpp(6): internal error: assertion failed: ensure_il_scope_exists: NULL IL scope (shared/cfe/edgcpfe/il.c, line 7439)

size_t MAX_SIZE = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()>
^

compilation aborted for source.cpp (code 4)
```

Comment: Another clang bug (in 4.0) `numeric_limts<type>max()` compiles, but `numeric_limits<type>(max)()` does not. It does compile with gcc though. The [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) package has this issue.

Comment: @user9645 That's disappointing... :( Clang 5.0 came out on Sep 7 this year. I wonder whether this issue is resolved in 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

To use C++11 library features with clang you need to use the libc++ standard library implementation, otherwise you get the ancient library from GCC 4.1.2, which doesn't support C++11

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790442/981959 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150421/981959 and many other questions.

Comment: Compiling with `clang++ -o foo.o -c -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -g -I. foo.cpp` changes nothing.